# Encryption Routine Not working, Can't figure out, subtle bug in it

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, cryptography

All,

Please look at the code below. The encrypt, decrypt code doesn't work correctly.
When I pass in the string "Hello world" I get back "Hello wo". I always lose bytes and can't figure it out why. There has to be a reason for this, subtle bug?

```
private static void _TestEncryption2()
    {
        var testText = "Hello world";
        var plainBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(testText);
        
        var cipher = Rijndael.Create();
        cipher.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        //var _key = Convert.FromBase64String(KEY);
        //var _IV = Convert.FromBase64String(IV);
        var _key = cipher.Key;
        var _IV = cipher.IV;

        byte[] cipherBytes;
        byte[] decryptedBytes;


        var enc = cipher.CreateEncryptor(_key, _IV);
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, enc, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cryptoStream.Write(plainBytes, 0, plainBytes.Length);
            }
            cipherBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
        }

        var dec = cipher.CreateDecryptor(_key, _IV);
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, dec, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cryptoStream.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);

                decryptedBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
            }
        }

        var decryptedText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(decryptedBytes);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dispose your second `cryptoStream` before doing `memoryStream.ToArray()`:

```
        var dec = cipher.CreateDecryptor(_key, _IV);
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, dec, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cryptoStream.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);
            }

            // Here
            decryptedBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
```

The problem is that the second `CryptoStream` hasn't been flushed before you read its output, and it's still holding onto that final block internally.

Your block size is 16 bytes, and you're using UTF-16 which uses 2 bytes per character, so the fact that you're getting the first block of 8 characters (16 bytes), but not the final block, makes sense here.

---

Also, `Encoding.Unicode` is UTF-16, which is a slightly odd choice in this day and age. Your default should be `Encoding.UTF8`.

Comment: Wow, how did I miss that :( Thanks!!! We selected UTF16 to match the Unicode string size in .net. Now that I think about it, UTF8 would be more efficient since we're talking about encoding.

Comment: Everyone gets the dispose order wrong with crypto stuff. I saw the title and suspected it; read the description and knew for sure, even before I read the code. You're in good company!